# LaTeX fragments look different to exported PDF (witharrows)

Tags: org-mode, org-export, preview-latex, math

I have problems getting correct latex fragments rendered. For some reason, they look different than the exported PDF, which looks fine.
What is not working is the package `witharrows`, to place vertical arrows in equations.

Org LaTeX equation:

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{WithArrows}
a\cdot{}x^{2} + b\cdot{}x + c &= 0   \Arrow[xoffset=1cm]{Test} \\
\frac{1}{2}
\end{WithArrows}
\end{equation*}
```

Which is rendered inline as:

[image: Inline fragment]

But the *arrow* should look like:

[image: Rendered PDF]

The arrow is way too small and does not stretch to the next line.
Is there some way to get the same output one gets when exporting to PDF?
Or is there any other similar package that would work?

What I have done so far is:
Adding `'("" "witharrows" t))` to my `org-latex-packages-alist` and
setting `'imagemagick` as `org-preview-latex-default-process` which helped to show the arrows at all.
For some reason, it did not work with `dvipng` at all.

Comment: I'm able to reproduce this but I don't know what causes it yet.

Comment: @NickD Do you know how to get the tex source org-mode generates for rendering the preview? Thanks.

Comment: Too long for a comment, so I posted an incomplete answer with my findings and a couple of debugging methods I use for Org mode LaTeX preview problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @NickD I have found a solution.

The solution is to register a custom `org-preview-latex-process` and run pdflatex/lualatex twice for generating the latex preview image:

```
(setq luamagick '(luamagick :programs ("lualatex" "convert")
       :description "pdf > png"
       :message "you need to install lualatex and imagemagick."
       :use-xcolor t
       :image-input-type "pdf"
       :image-output-type "png"
       :image-size-adjust (1.0 . 1.0)
       :latex-compiler ("lualatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f && lualatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f") ;; <-- HERE
       :image-converter ("convert -density %D -trim -antialias %f -quality 100 %O")))

(add-to-list 'org-preview-latex-process-alist luamagick)
(setq org-preview-latex-default-process 'luamagick)
```

`witharrows` seems to be need to run twice to produce the correct output.

Comment: Nice find! I think the reason that `lualatex` works, whereas `pdflatex` does not is that `lualatex` (like `xelatex`) supports Unicode out of the box; `pdflatex` does not (there are some hacks that you can do with `pdflatex` to more or less  deal with Unicode but they are hacks. It seems that the `witharrows` package needs Unicode in order to work properly. I tried with `xelatex` as well and that works too.

Comment: BTW, the "running twice" is a standard LaTeX gotcha and has nothing to do with `witharrows`: it's just that you need to run LaTeX (*any* LaTex) multiple times in order to produce the files that it needs (e.g for table of contents, list of figures, glossaries, bibliographies etc). That's why things like `latexmk` exist.

Answer (score 1):

[Not a complete answer: in the first part, I show the TeX file for the preview and identify the problematic component of the pipeline, but I don't know *why* that component misbehaves. In the second part, I describe a couple of debugging methods for Org mode LaTeX preview problems that I've used in the past - and used here to get the TeX file in the first part of the "answer"].

***The TeX File***

The problem here is that in the `imagemagick` pipeline (which indeed works better than the `dvipng` pipeline, which does not work at all with the `witharrows` package), the fragment is turned into a `LaTeX` file that is then processed through `pdflatex` to a `PDF` file  and that in turn is processed through `convert` (part of the ImageMagick suite of programs) to produce a `PNG` file.

The `LaTeX` file looks like this in its entirety - you should be able to cut-and-paste it into your own file, process it through `pdflatex` and verify that the resulting `PDF` file looks correct:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
% Package minted omitted
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% Package longtable omitted
% Package wrapfig omitted
% Package rotating omitted
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
% Package capt-of omitted
% Package hyperref omitted
\pagestyle{empty}             % do not remove
% The settings below are copied from fullpage.sty
\setlength{\textwidth}{\paperwidth}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{-3cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{1.5cm}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-2.54cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{\oddsidemargin}
\setlength{\textheight}{\paperheight}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-\headheight}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-\headsep}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-\footskip}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-3cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{1.5cm}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-2.54cm}

\usepackage{witharrows}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{fg}{rgb}{0,1,0}%
\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0,0,0}%

\pagecolor{bg}%

{\color{fg}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{WithArrows}
a\cdot{}x^{2} + b\cdot{}x + c &= 0   \Arrow[xoffset=1cm]{Test} \\
\frac{1}{2}
\end{WithArrows}
\end{equation*}
%
}

\end{document}
```

Processing this through `pdflatex` produces a `PDF` file that looks correct, with the arrow pointing from the first line to the fraction. But for some reason, `convert` mucks up the `PNG` output the way you've shown. Why that is remains a mystery, but I guess it's either a bug in `convert` or an incompatibility with the `PDF` that is produced for the arrow. **EDIT: This is almost certainly wrong. See the OP's answer for a solution. It seems that `pdflatex` is indeed to blame.**

***Debugging Techniques***

Diagnosing problems in `org-latex-preview` is often an exercise in frustration. The problem is that the underlying `org-create-formula-image` takes the LaTeX fragment as a string argument and then internally it writes a `.tex` file containing the LaTeX header and the fragment (with enough additional stuff to make it into a legal LaTeX file), it processes the file (to either `dvi` or `pdf` depending on the value of `org-preview-latex-process`) and then converts that file to a `PNG` image (using either `dvipng` or `convert` - the `imagemagick` method goes the `pdflatex/convert` route). The function then copies the output file to the `ltximg/` subdirectory of wherever the Org mode file is and then *cleans up everything*, leaving no trace of what it did and how it did it.

I have used one of two methods to debug such problems:

- I instrument `org-create-formula-image` with [edebug](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Edebug.html) and single-step through the function almost all the way to the end to just before the loop that does the clean up. That code looks like this:

```el
      ...
      (copy-file image-output-file tofile 'replace)
      (dolist (e post-clean)
        (when (file-exists-p (concat texfilebase e))
          (delete-file (concat texfilebase e))))
      image-output-file)))
```

You want to stop just *before* this point. Then I examine various things with the `e` command. In particular, the variable `texfile` contains the path of the `.tex` file that is used to generate the `.pdf` file and thence the `.png` file. In most cases, I just go to a terminal and copy that file to a safe place and then process it through the rest of the pipeline (`pdflatex` and `convert` in the `imagemagick` case.

- Another method I have used is to copy the source code of the function `org-create-formula-image`, modify it and then load the modified version into Emacs. For example, I replace the few lines shown above with the following:

```el
      ...
      (copy-file image-output-file tofile 'replace)
      (print latex-compiler t)
      (message texfile)
      (print image-converter t)
      (message image-input-file)
      (message image-output-type)
      ;; (dolist (e post-clean)
      ;;   (when (file-exists-p (concat texfilebase e))
      ;;     (delete-file (concat texfilebase e))))
      image-output-file)))
```

where I've commented out the clean-up loop and added some `message` and `print` calls to print out interesting stuff. I then evaluate the defun with `C-x C-e` after the closing paren and do `C-c C-x C-l` to do the LaTeX preview in the Org mode buffer. I can then check what was printed out by visiting the `*Messages` buffer. After I am done, I reload the official `org.el[c]` file to restore the previous definition of the function.

Comment: Many many thanks! I found a solution, see my answer. Your answer helped me a lot!

Comment: … but I have also discovered that there are still problems. Maybe `witharrows` does not work that well at all? I will give up on it…

Comment: What other problems have you encountered that cannot be resolved by the use of `lualatex` or `xelatex`?

Comment: My goal is to write “steps” on the right side of equations, e.G. `\frac{1}{x}   | \times x`, where the equation should be left and/or = aligned, and the “step description” should be left aligned on a second or third column.